# Need help about detecting license plate numbers using Android Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to find a license plate number in a text matching a pattern like this below
("L" stands for a letter,"D" stands for a number):

LLLDDD,LLLDDDD,LLDDDD,DDDDLL

there can be spaces between them like LLL DDD

I have this method that works fine if the text is just the license plate number like for example "SS1234"

```
public static boolean plateNumberExist(String target) {
    return Pattern.compile("^([A-Za-z]{3} ?[0-9]{3})?([A-Za-z]{3} ?[0-9]{4})?([A-Za-z]{2} ?[0-9]{4})?([0-9]{4} ?[A-Za-z]{2})?$").matcher(target).matches();
}
```

But if i add another text with the license plate number like the code below then its always false

```
if(plateNumberExist("Republic SS1234")){
    showToast("Plate Number Found");
}else{
    showToast("No Plate Number");
}
```

So the actual code that i am using to get the license plate number is the code below but it also doesn't work.

```
String inputString = "Republic SS1234";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([A-Za-z]{3} ?[0-9]{3})?([A-Za-z]{3} ?[0-9]{4})?([A-Za-z]{2} ?[0-9]{4})?([0-9]{4} ?[A-Za-z]{2})?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
if (matcher.find()) {
   String platenumber = inputString.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                showToast(platenumber);
            } else {
                showToast("No Plate Number Found");
            }
```

The problem is with the regex but i just don't understand why it works if its only a license plate number but if i have other text with the license plate number it doesn't work

Comment: and what is that "other text" that "doesnt work"?

Comment: like "Republic SS1234" the other text is Republic

Comment: Search what `^` and `$`match in a regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` and `$` regex symbols denote the beginning and end of the input, respectively.

Replace those with `\\b` (beginning/end of a word), and it should work.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/JKNMLz/1)

**== Edit ==**

Note that your regex itself can be simplified and you should use a loop if you want to collect all matches. Have a look:

```
String inputString = "Republic SS1234 and ABC 1234";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "(?i)\\b([A-Z]{3} ?[0-9]{3,4}|[A-Z]{2} ?[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4} ?[A-Z]{2})\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String platenumber = matcher.group(1);
    . . .
}
```

`(?i)` means ignore-case, `{3,4}` means "from 3 to 4" and `|` means "or"

Comment: I see a few things in the OP's pattern which might still not work even after switching to word boundaries, but your answer is basically the right thing to do +1.

Comment: Thank you so much!